# how to replace range with function output, and overwrite the range value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code that looks like this, trying to replace a cell with the output of the function FuzzyVLookup, currently, i can read the cell mAr(i,1) and have an output for FuzzyVLookup(mAr(i,1), inRng1 ,1) but i cant overwrite the initial mAr(i,1)

thank you in advance for the help

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

'Remember time when macro starts
StartTime = Timer
    '---------------------------------------------------------------
    '-- Select Range A for comparison to be compared with Range B --
    '---------------------------------------------------------------
    Const LBLS  As String = "Names to be matched "
    Const xNAME As String = "Fuzzy Match Lead"

    Set inRng = Application.Selection
    Set inRng = Application.InputBox(LBLS, xNAME, inRng.Address, Type:=8)

    '-----------------------------------------------
    '-- Select Range B for Range A to be compared --
    '-----------------------------------------------
    Const LBLS1  As String = "Names to be matched to "
    Const xNAME1 As String = "Fuzzy Match Source"

    Set inRng1 = Application.Selection
    Set inRng1 = Application.InputBox(LBLS1, xNAME1, inRng.Address, Type:=8)

    If inRng.Columns.Count > 1 Or inRng.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a single (continuous) column"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    allRows = inRng.Rows.Count
    If inRng.Count = 1 Then     'if only one cell selected force mAr to array
        ReDim mAr(1, 1)
        mAr(1, 1) = inRng.Value2
    Else
        mAr = inRng.Value2
    End If

    For i = 1 To allRows
        mAr(i, 1) = FuzzyVLookup(mAr(i, 1), inRng1, 1)
    Next

    inRng = mAr                 'place memory array back to range

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

'Notify user in seconds
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation


End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing? Writing the array to range? Or does MsgBox mAr(i,1) display an empty value?

Comment: Nvm I get it. Try Dim mAr(1 to 1, 1 to 1). Your range is a cell, but an array starts at index 0 by default.

Comment: @Christov hi thank you for commenting, i tried running the code after putting Dim mAr(1 To 1, 1 To 1), i encountered a compile error: array being dimensioned, am i doing smth wrong?

im hoping these lines would have rewrite and replace the values to values in inRng1. However, there was no change to the inRng even though these 2 lines were implemented   

 (1)       mAr(i, 1) = FuzzyVLookup(mAr(i, 1), inRng1, 1)
and 
 (2)      inRng = mAr

Comment: So replace `ReDim mAr(1,1)` by `ReDim mAr(1 to 1, 1 to 1)`.

Comment: @Christov hi, i tried replacing the line and tested the code. it still does not work. just curious, redim will be applied only when i select one row in my inRng right?

or will it be applied to the whole code?

Comment: How did you declare `mArr`? I do not see its declaration. I would suggest declarig it in this way `Dim mArr as Variant`. Then use `mArr = inRng.Value2` independent of `inRng.Rows.Count`. Please condition the loop according to `Ubound(mArr)` to be >0. Then use `inRng.|Value = mAr'. A Variant variable can become an array for more cells in the range, or a String/Long keeping the cell value for a single cell in the range... Arrays obtained in this way are in Base 1.

Comment: @FaneDuru hi, i dont really understand this,  '  Then use `inRng.|Value = mAr'. A Variant variable can become an array for more cells in the range, or a String/Long keeping the cell value for a single cell in the range... Arrays obtained in this way are in Base 1.  '

```inRng.|Value = mAr``` how do i code this?

Comment: Whey I wrote (blind) `inRng.|Value = mAr` that vertical bar has been introduced by mistake. You have to replace `inRng = mAr` with `inRng.Value = mAr`.  If you declare `mAr as Variant` it will become an array if your range has more then one cell. Isn't it clear? And just `Long` or `String` according to the cell value type in case of only one cell in that range. Can you test what I suggested?

Comment: @FaneDuru hi i tested the code by changing the line, it works! thank you for the help!